# Python websockets - how to connect after timeout in asyncio loop?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm running an asyncio loop in the code below to retrieve data using websockets. Occasionally the network connection drops or the server is unresponsive so I have introduced a `timeout` which is caught by an exception handler. The `timeout` enables me to stop the connection quickly before I get a connection error message.

However, once the network connection is re-established or the server is back online, I am not sure how to connect to the server again so I can carry on running my loop as before?

I also get the following errors `ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` and `websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: no close frame received or sent`.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError as ConnectionTimeoutError

async def call_dapi():
    async with websockets.connect('wss://test.deribit.com/ws/api/v2') as websocket:
        while True:
            try:
                msg = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "public/get_order_book", "id": 1, "params": {"instrument_name": "BTC-PERPETUAL"}, "depth": "5"}
                await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg))
                response = await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.recv(), timeout=2)
                response = json.loads(response)
                print(response)
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
            except ConnectionTimeoutError as e:
                print('Error connecting.')
                pass

asyncio.ensure_future(call_dapi())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: You have to loop back around to the `websockets.connect` call again.  You'll need a second loop.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you but how do I do that exactly? Would you mind providing the code if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: I suppose I can, but it seems pretty obvious.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks. I hadn't come across nested loops before. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and introducing something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but this is the philosophy.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError as ConnectionTimeoutError

async def call_dapi():
    while True:
        async with websockets.connect('wss://test.deribit.com/ws/api/v2') as websocket:
            live = True
            while live:
                try:
                    msg = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "public/get_order_book", "id": 1, "params": {"instrument_name": "BTC-PERPETUAL"}, "depth": "5"}
                    await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg))
                    response = await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.recv(), timeout=2)
                    response = json.loads(response)
                    print(response)
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                except ConnectionTimeoutError as e:
                    print('Error connecting.')
                    live = False

asyncio.ensure_future(call_dapi())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```